# How to trigger inbound-channel-adapter on adhoc basis?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

My configuration looks something like below where I am using Inbound channel Adapter to trigger a bean class to generate a file send on daily basis. I need facility to run this on adhoc basis also apart from scheduled job. I can't see any way to do that.

The only way I can think of is get the instance of SourcePollingChannelAdapter, set the new trigger (with new cron expression) and restart the endpoint. Let me know if there is any better way to do this.

```
<int:inbound-channel-adapter ref="xxxTask" method="executeXXXTask" channel="fileOutChannel">
    <int:poller cron="0 30 4 ? * *"/>
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is ok.

Or, you can poll more frequently and add a `PollSkipAdvice` to ignore polls. Add a custom `PollSkipStrategy` (or use a `SimplePollSkipStrategy`) to enable/disable the poll.

A custom strategy could use an `AtomicBoolean.getAndSet()` for a one-shot poll (with the trigger setting it).

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#pollable-message-source). Also see [Smart Pollers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#conditional-pollers).

Comment: Thanks Gary for confirming my understanding. I will try other suggestions as well.